# Как применить проверку номера телефона?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, исключения

Решаю задачу, в ней есть метод `аddCustomer`. Этот метод формирует строку из данных клиента (имя, фамилия, почта, телефон) и добавляет ее в коллекцию HashMap. Сейчас он проверяет на ошибки, длину строки и, что бы ввод данных был через пробел. Но мне надо, что бы он заодно проверял и соответствие вводимого номера телефона установленному формату.

Вопрос в том, как правильно применить в этом методе регулярное выражение, чтобы метод проверял, правильно ли введен номер, ну и как следствие, чтобы я мог в случае ошибки добавить его в исключение и программа не вылетала. Шаблон для номера я написал, но как-то в метод вставил коряво.

```
public CustomerStorage() {
    storage = new HashMap<>();
}

public void addCustomer(String data) {
    final int INDEX_NAME = 0;
    final int INDEX_SURNAME = 1;
    final int INDEX_EMAIL = 2;
    final String INDEX_PHONE = String.valueOf(3);

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(\\+7)([0-9]{10})$");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(INDEX_PHONE);

    String[] components = data.split("\\s+");
    if(components.length !=4)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Неверный формат. Верный формат: \n" +
                "add Имя Фамилия name@mail.ru +71234567890");

    }
    String name = components[INDEX_NAME] + " " + components[INDEX_SURNAME];
    storage.put(name, new Customer(name, components[Integer.parseInt(INDEX_PHONE)], components[INDEX_EMAIL]));

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В своём коде вы сопоставляете с шаблоном **индекс телефона** в исходной строке, а не саму подстроку.  Кроме того, проверка шаблона при помощи `Matcher::matches/Matcher::find`так и не вызывается.

И наконец, преобразовывать строку из 11 цифр в тип `int` для хранения номера телефона -- более чем странная идея, так как максимальное значение составляет `Integer.MAX_VALUE = 2147483647`, и этого типа данных явно не хватит для хранения любых значений даже без учёта начальной 7 в коде страны.

Для проверки строки на определенный формат достаточно использовать метод `String::matches`, отдельная регулярка не требуется.

```java
public void addCustomer(String data) {
    final int INDEX_NAME = 0;
    final int INDEX_SURNAME = 1;
    final int INDEX_EMAIL = 2;
    final int INDEX_PHONE = 3;

    final String PHONE_TEMPLATE = "+7\\d{10}";

    String[] components = data.split("\\s+");
    if (components.length != 4) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Неверный формат. Верный формат: \n" +
                "add Имя Фамилия name@mail.ru +71234567890");
    }
    String phone = components[INDEX_PHONE];
    if (!phone.matches(PHONE_TEMPLATE)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Неверный формат телефона в строке " + phone);
    } 
    String name = components[INDEX_NAME] + " " + components[INDEX_SURNAME];
    storage.put(name, new Customer(name, phone, components[INDEX_EMAIL]));

}
```

Comment: Да, это то, что нужно, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Я не понял,но  где непосредственно вы в своем коде проверяете номер телефона?
где метод find()?

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\(?\\b([0-9]{3})\\)?[-.•]?([0-9]{3})[-.•]?([0-9]{4})\\b");

Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(inString);
Strng numer="";
while (regexMatcher.find()) {
    numer = regexMatcher.group();//  проверяем в строке наличие номера телефона 
}
System.out.println(numer)
```